# Gitlab-CI: Bind mount failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to configure Gitlab CI for my dockerized Symfony project.

In the test phase, I try to start my docker-compose.yml, where one service needs a bind mount. My runner **does see** the folder, but I cannot use it.
I get as test output:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose_deploy.yml up -d
Creating network "xxx_default" with the default driver
Creating xxx_php_1   ... 
Creating xxx_db_1    ... 

Creating xxx_php_1   ... done
Creating xxx_nginx_1 ... 

Creating xxx_db_1    ... error

ERROR: for xxx_db_1  Cannot start service db: Bind mount failed: '/backups' does not exists
```

To test that I included the command `ls /` in my `before_script` section. But it does show `/backups`, since I altered my runners' config.toml:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "main-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "xyz"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock","/volume1/docker/postgres-backup:/backups", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Here's the important part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
before_script:
  - ls /
  - docker info
  - apk add --update py-pip && pip install docker-compose
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose_deploy.yml build --pull 

test1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose_deploy.yml up -d
    - docker exec registry.gitlab.com/xxx-group/xxx_php_1 bash docker/php-fpm/initialization.sh
    - docker exec registry.gitlab.com/xxx-group/xxx_php_1 bin/console app:initialize
    - docker exec registry.gitlab.com/xxx-group/xxx_php_1 ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit
  after_script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose_deploy.yml down
```

The docker-compose.yml is

```
volumes:
    pgdata:
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:9-alpine
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - /backups:/backups
```

Although the built images cannot be executed, I can `inspect` them:
And the volume in fact is not listed there!

```
"Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running docker-in-docker with a shared socket. This means that you have a Gitlab CI runner host (a.k.a HOST) and a job running **in a container** based on `docker:latest` (a.k.a JOBCONTAINER).

Your assumption is that you can mount files that exist in your JOBCONTAINER (the ones you see when you `ls` in your `before_script`) when in fact the actual container you are starting with `docker-compose` **will run in context of the HOST** since you are using its Docker daemon inside your JOBCONTAINER.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat Stefan von Gastel's correct answer:

When running the test (and docker-compose'ing `up`), in my setting, the docker commands run in the context of the docker host, i.e. the machine that executes the gitlab-runner.

So to stay in my config, a simple

```
$ ln -s  /volume1/docker/postgres-backup/ /backups
```

solved my problem, because now the path is available. In fact, the entry in `volumes` in my runner's `config.toml` are unneccessary.

**THANKS Stefan!**